# jquery open url in popup window with height + weight and pass a param to it

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup, parameter-passing

Im trying to load on the click of a div a url but in a new window with certain sizes. For example I would have

```
<div id="mydiv>
   Roy
  click on this div
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="mydiv>
   Alex
  click on this div
</div>
```

Then the idea is a new window will popup ( not a modal ) with say sizes like 300x400px.
The username should be passed to this window and I want to be able to do something with it in my web application. Jquery just needs to call something like /chatwindow/?user=rob

What would be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, try this

```
<div id="mydiv-alex" class="mydiv">
    Alex click on this div
</div>
<div id="mydiv-jonh" class="mydiv">
    Jonh click on this div
</div>
<script>
    $('.mydiv').click(function(){
    window.open(' /chatwindow/?user='+$(this).attr('id').replace('mydiv-',''), '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<div id="mydiv">
   Alex
  click on this div
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowSizeArray = [ "width=200,height=200",
                                "width=300,height=400,scrollbars=yes" ];

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mydiv').click(function (event){

                var url ="www.yourdomain.com/chatwindow/?user=rob";
                var windowName = "popUp";//$(this).attr("name");
                var windowSize = windowSizeArray[ $(this).attr("rel") ];

                window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span id="username">Alex</span> click on this div
</div>
<script>
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    window.open(' /chatwindow/?user='+$('#username').text(), '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
return false;
});
</script>
```

Or this

```
<div id="mydiv">
    Alex click on this div
</div>
<script>
var username = 'Alex';
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    window.open(' /chatwindow/?user='+username, '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
return false;
});
</script>
```

Or this

```
<div id="mydiv">
    Alex click on this div
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="Alex">
</div>
<script>
var username = 'Alex';
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    window.open(' /chatwindow/?user='+$('#mydiv > input[name="username"]').val(), '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok thx! that is almost it but the 1 JS script has to facilitate the multiple divs, So a way to pass the username from an element like id="alex" and use that and pass that then it would be exactly like question

Comment: Ok then:
    <div id="mydiv-alex" class="mydiv">
        Alex click on this div
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv-jonh" class="mydiv">
        Jonh click on this div
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.mydiv').click(function(){
        window.open(' /chatwindow/?user='+$(this).attr('id').replace('mydiv-',''), '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
        return false;
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/open-link-in-new-tab-or-new-popup.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('A.BLAH').click(function() {
var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=600,width=1000');
if (window.focus)
{
NWin.focus();
}
return false;
});
});
```